# Numerate divs alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of letters from A to U, according to which I should be numerating the dynamically generated divs

```
const alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"]

$(".numeration").each(function () {
        for (let i = 0; i <= alphabetArray.length; i++) {
                $(".numeration").html(alphabetArray[i]);
        }
})
```

there is one issue though, every div is numerated as U, the last element in the array. I know I am overlooking something simple in this logic but I can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: You have a nested loop. For every 'div.numeration', you iterate over your complete 'alphabetArray' where the last value is 'U'.

Comment: Just use `$(".numeration").html(function(i) { return aplhabetArray[i]; });` instead. Provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is, that `$(".numeration").html()` accesses every element in that group.

You are basically setting the current letter for all elements matching that selector.

If you only want to execute the current object of the "each" you need to use `$(this).html();` instead

The second problem is your nested loop of your alphabetArray. You are basically overwriting the current value until you reach the end of your array (hence why only the last element shows up).

If you try something like this you should be closer to your goal:

```
const alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"]

$(".numeration").each(function (index) {
  $(this).html(alphabetArray[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **eq()** method to select element.

Check out this for refrence:- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_eq.asp

```
const alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"]

$(".numeration").each(function (i) {
  
    $(".numeration").eq(i).html(alphabetArray[i]);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` already considers your elements collection (just like `.each()`) with an index as its first argument. You can then use the `return` (or *implicit return* if you use arrow functions `=>` ) and use that index:

```js
const alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"];

$(".numeration").html(i => alphabetArray[i]);
```

```html
  <div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, nowadays jQuery is not necessary:

```js
const alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"];

document.querySelectorAll(".numeration").forEach((el, i) => {
  el.textContent = alphabetArray[i]
});
```

```html
<div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div><div class="numeration"></div>
```

Comment: Personally - and this *isn't* worth a separate answer - I'd amend Roko's code to something similar to the following [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L3sfe6bm/), depending on any requirement for using, or switching between, upper- and lower-case; though CSS could easily achieve the same: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L3sfe6bm/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas that's exactly what I wanted to add to as a third example to my answer, but just decided to not do it. An UTF-16 sequence of uppercase characters from A-U can be achieved by adding `65` to an incrementing `i` index in combination with `String.fromCharCode` just like you did. Nice use of `content: counter(alphaCounter, upper-alpha);` - this one might deserve an answer on its own.

Comment: Thanks! As for using the CSS `counter(...)`, it doesn't really address the question given that OP is looking for a jQuery/JavaScript solution (so far as I can tell), but if you'd like to add it to your own answer - for completion - please do feel free :)